# SQL Sanitization Output/Datatype Error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm attempting to sanitize the input of some PHP/SQL code, but I keep receiving the following error when checking the number of rows:

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

It feels like I'm missing a method to convert/handle the query after execution, and there is little in the documentation to bridge this gap. Assuming $conn is a properly connected mysqli database call, here is my code:

```
    $qry = mysqli_prepare($conn,'SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute=?');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($qry,'s',$_SESSION['string']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($qry);  

    /* Should something go here? */

    if(mysqli_num_rows($qry) > 0)
        {
        //foo
        }
```

I avoided object notation because it wasn't working either - this simply appeared a little more explicit, but I'm not opposed to either method.

Looking forward to hearing any thoughts - thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use mysqli very often, but I believe the issue stems from the fact you are trying to call the mysqli_num_rows() method against a sql string. After running the execute command, pull the results of the execution into a variable and pass that into your mysqli_num_rows() call.

```
// Added this to capture the results of the execution 
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    //foo
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was able to discover a way to count the number of rows and retrieve the db output:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'SELECT blah FROM table WHERE attribute=?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$string);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$bindingvar);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
//foo
}
```

And output is now assigned to `$bindingvar`.

It's cumbersome, but it does everything I want it to, and it's nice and procedural.

It should be noted this method doesn't work well for more than one result from a database, but given the level of problems with "get_result()" this is far better than nothing.

Hope this helps!

- M